# Vertical alignment of TMS tiles in Leaflet using EPSG:25832 projection

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, proj4js

I am using Leaflet with Proj4Leaflet to work with tiles in 25832. The application is fairly simple: I am trying to overlay tiles in EPSG:25832 onto a omniscale basemap. I have copied the individual resolutions and origin from the tilemap meta information. The problem I am facing is that the map is not aligned and once I zoom in the tiles are not placed in the correct order. I'd appreciate any kind of support here (by the way, [this](https://www.bmvi.de/DE/Themen/Digitales/Breitbandausbau/Breitbandatlas-Karte/start.html) is a working example which is using openlayers).

I guess I am doing something wrong here:

```
// Set resolutions
var resolutions = [156367.7919628329,78183.89598141646,39091.94799070823,19545.973995354114,9772.986997677057,4886.4934988385285,2443.2467494192642,1221.6233747096321,610.8116873548161,305.40584367740803,152.70292183870401,76.35146091935201,38.175730459676004,19.087865229838002,9.543932614919001,4.7719663074595005,2.3859831537297502,1.1929915768648751];

// Define CRS
var rs25832 = new L.Proj.CRS(
    'EPSG:25832',
    proj4rs25832def, 
    {
        origin: [ 273211.2532533697, 6111822.37943825 ],
        resolutions: resolutions
    }
);
```

...using the tiles information from https://mapproxy.bba.atenekom.eu/tms/1.0.0/privat_alle_50_mbit/germany .

Afterwards I add a tile layer

```
var url = 'https://mapproxy.bba.atenekom.eu/tms/1.0.0/privat_alle_50_mbit/germany/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';  

var tileLayer = L.tileLayer(
    url, 
    {
        tms: true,
        crs: rs25832,
        continuousWorld: true,
        maxZoom: resolutions.length
    }
);
```

And add them to the map..

```
// Setup map
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: rs25832,
    center: [ 50.8805, 7.3389 ],
    zoom:5,
    maxZoom: resolutions.length,
    layers: [ baseWms, tileLayer ]
});
```

The bare minimum of code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/6gcam7w5/8/

[image: incorrect alignment]

Comment: could you confirm that Proj4Leaflet worked just fine with leafet@1.6.0? since in their repo, it's mentioned to support leaflet@1.0.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This boils down to how the Y coordinate of [TMS](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification) tiles is inverted (it becomes higher when going north, as opposed to default `TileLayer`s, in which the Y coordinate becomes larger when going south).

Having a look on the [Leaflet code that takes care of this specific feature](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L177-L183) will shed some light on the issue:

```
    if (this._map && !this._map.options.crs.infinite) {
        var invertedY = this._globalTileRange.max.y - coords.y;
        if (this.options.tms) {
            data['y'] = invertedY;
        }
        data['-y'] = invertedY;
    }
```

There are two things critical to calculating the right Y coordinate for your tiles here:

- The CRS must be finite (it must have bounds)
- There must be a finite global tile range (which in Leaflet is [ultimately defined](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/e8c28b996179373447dde1df479898576a508579/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js#L609) by the CRS bounds and not the `TileLayer` bounds)

Long story short, your CRS should be defined with known bounds. For this particular case, taking information from the [TMS capabilities document](https://mapproxy.bba.atenekom.eu/tms/1.0.0/privat_alle_50_mbit/germany)...

```
<BoundingBox minx="273211.2532533697" miny="5200000.0" maxx="961083.6232988155" maxy="6111822.37943825"/>
```

...and turned into a `L.Bounds` definition when defining the Leaflet CRS, like...

```
// Define CRS
var rs25832 = new L.Proj.CRS(
    'EPSG:25832',
    proj4rs25832def, 
    {
        origin: [ 273211.2532533697, 6111822.37943825 ],
        resolutions: resolutions,
        bounds: [[273211.2532533697, 5200000],[961083.6232988155, 6111822.37943825]]
    }
);
```

Stuff should just work (with no need to pass the CRS to the tilelayers, since they will all use the map's), as in this [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/qzLhax5r/).

Comment: Ivan , you rock. Thanks for for the explanation, my head is finally wrapped around, eureka!